# Transfer SQL job to another machine

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-job

How can I transfer my SQL Agent job (maintenance plan) from my server to another server?

I use SQL Server 2008 R2. My job runs a T-SQL script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem in this way:
I use SSIS to transfer SQL Agent job (maintenance plan) from my server to another server.
this is the way that i use:

1. Open SSIS and go to Stored package --> MSDB  --> maintenance plan and right click on your job and choose export
2. choose file system for location
3. choose the path for your package
4. copy your file in new server
5. connect to another machines SSIS
6. now choose import package on MSDB
7. go to maintenance plan and save your job or run Creat script

Answer (score 1):

The following article explains how to to do it: [Migrating a Maintenance Plan from One SQL Server to Another](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3066351/Migrating-a-Maintenance-Plan-from-One-SQL-Server-to-Another.htm).

Note that they're using SQL Server 2000, but it should work for SQL Server 2008 R2 as well.